# Dynamically create rect inside svg based on data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm just started to learning D3 and wanted to create dynamically `<rect>` inside SVG, which is inside a div.

This is the html:

```
<div class="canvas">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

And this is the JS I tried:

```
var data = [
  {width: 300, height: 100, fill: 'purple'}
];
var c = d3.select('.canvas');
var r = c.select('svg').append('rect');//first creating an rect.
r.selectAll('rect').data(data)//then select whatever the rect i have inside svg
.enter().append('rect')
.attr('width', f=>f.width)
.attr('height', f=>f.height)
.attr('fill', f=>f.fill);
```

It's showing no errors at all. I Don't know where the actual fault is here. Searching everywhere but not finding any suitable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `r` selection...

```
var r = c.select('svg').append('rect');
```

... corresponds to a `<rect>` element. Because of that, your enter selection...

```
r.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  //etc...
```

... is appending a rect inside another rect:

```
<svg>
    <rect>
        <rect width="300" height="100" fill="purple"></rect>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

That, of course, doesn't work.

Therefore, it should be:

```
var r = c.select('svg').selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  //etc...
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var data = [{
  width: 300,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'purple'
}];
var c = d3.select('.canvas');
var r = c.select('svg').selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', f => f.width)
  .attr('height', f => f.height)
  .attr('fill', f => f.fill);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo, it working fine as expected. Previously i thought if element is not present, then calling `select()` will throw error, that's why i append `rect` first.